# Angular's FormControl method markAsTouched not working in a test case

Tags: angular6, angular-test

I have this function which checks that the `password` and `confirmPassword` fields have the same value. If not, the form is marked a `invalid`

```
confirmPasswordValidator(passwordGroupForm: AbstractControl){

    let password = passwordGroupForm.get('password');
    let confirmPassword = passwordGroupForm.get('confirmPassword');
    console.log("password is "+password +"and confirmPassword is "+confirmPassword);


    console.log("confirm password touched",confirmPassword.touched );
    if(!confirmPassword.touched) return null ;//don't mark form invalid if the user hasn't interacted with confirmPassword field
    else {
      return (password.value === confirmPassword.value) ? null : {
          confirmPasswordValidator: {
            valid: false,
            message: 'Password and Verify Password fields do not match'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have written the following test case to check that the function works.

```
it('should not submit form if password and confirm password are not the same',()=>{
    let formControls = component.signupForm.controls;
    let userService = TestBed.get(UserManagementService);
    spyOn(userService,'addUser');
    formControls['firstName'].setValue("first");
    formControls['lastName'].setValue("last");
    formControls['email'].setValue("e@e.com");
    formControls['password'].setValue("aA1!1111");
    formControls['confirmPassword'].setValue("aA1!11112");

    fixture.detectChanges();
    formControls['confirmPassword'].markAsTouched();
console.log("after control touched, touch value is",formControls['confirmPassword'].markAsTouched());
    component.addUser();
    expect(component.signupForm.valid).toBeFalsy();
    expect(userService.addUser).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But the test case is failing with error `Expected true to be falsy.` In the browser window I can see that it is showing `touched` property as `true` as well as `false`!! (see the picture)

[image]

I can see that the `confirmPassword` field is not touched. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I had to mark the field dirty before setting its value

```
formControls['confirmPassword'].markAsTouched({onlySelf:true});
    formControls['confirmPassword'].setValue("aA1!11112");
```

It seems `setValue` runs the form validation and as the field is not marked touched at that time, the `confirmPasswordValidator` is run by Angular and it returns `null` making the form valid. Calling `markAsTouched` doesn't re-run the form validation and `addUser` then finds the form valid.

Comment: sometimes calling setValue is needed - sometimes not...